# A variable as key automatically become a string when building a dictionary

Tags: javascript, dictionary

Here is a sample code

```
var dict={};
var word="123";
dict["aaa"]={word:1}
console.log(dict)
```

Is there a way to prevent the variable treating as string without using third party libraries?

In this case, I want the dict to become:

```
{"aaa":{"123":1}}
```

Instead of:

```
{"aaa":{"word":1}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript will interpret `word` as the key, even though you are defining `word` as a variable.

You can set the key with a variable using the following:

```
 var word = "123";
 var dict = {'aaa': {} };
 dict["aaa"][word] = 1;
 console.log(dict)

 >>> {"aaa":{ "123": 1 } }
```